# How to convert decimal timestamp to date in Java with trailing decimals

Tags: java, date, calendar, bigdecimal

I have been trying to figure out how to convert a timestamp to a date but with the trailing decimals at the end, so for example:
Timestamp - C50204EC EC42EE92 is equivalent to Sep 27, 2004 03:18:04.922896299 UTC.

The timestamp format includes the first 32-bit unsigned seconds as a field spanning 136 years and the 32-bit fraction field resolving 232 [picoseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picosecond). In the timestamp formats, the prime epoch, or base date of era 0, is 0 h 1 January 1900 UTC, when all bits are zero.

This is what I have written for my code so far:

```
    BigDecimal bi = new BigDecimal("1096255084000");
    double decimal_timestamp = bi.doubleValue();

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(decimal_timestamp);
    String date = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

    System.out.println(decimal_timestamp + " = " + date);
```

My thought is that it is probably not possible with calendar, so I'll have to do it from scratch, but I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Comment: Are you using java 8 or newer? You probably should consider using one of the new time related classes, e.g.: LocalDateTime. "Time is represented to nanosecond precision" - is that enough for you?

Comment: As an aside: so you will hit a year 2036 problem in 17 years.

Comment: From what system are you quoting that documentation? Put a mention in your title or question for others to find.

Comment: @BasilBourque Whoops, that was not meant to be in quotes.Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Winsome If this input style comes from some third-party library or system, please mention the name. It may help others in the future find this page. And I’m curious.

Comment: @BasilBourque A possible source seems to be one of the formats described in [RFC 5905](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5905.txt) section 6 *Data Types*. It’s related to NTP, which may contribute to explaining the unusually fine resolution.

Comment: @OleV.V. I see you mean *RFC 5905 Network Time Protocol Version 4: Protocol and Algorithms Specification*, for the [Network Time Protocol (NTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). Thanks, that interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

Using the example from the explanation:

> Timestamp - C50204EC EC42EE92 is equivalent to Sep 27, 2004
>   03:18:04.922896299 UTC.

```
    Instant epoch = OffsetDateTime.of(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();

    BigInteger timeStamp = new BigInteger("C50204ECEC42EE92", 16);

    // To get the whole part and the fraction right, divide by 2^32
    double secondsSince1900 = timeStamp.doubleValue() / 0x1_0000_0000L;

    // Convert seconds to nanos by multiplying by 1 000 000 000
    Instant converted = epoch.plusNanos(Math.round(secondsSince1900 * 1_000_000_000L));
    System.out.println(converted);
```

Output is:

> 2004-09-27T03:18:04.922896384Z

It’s off by 85 nanoseconds. Likely better floating-point arithmetic can do even better. Edit: A little loss of precision is unavoidable since the original time stamp has a resolution of 2^-32 seconds, which is more than 4 times as fine as the nanosecond (10^-9 second) resolution of `Instant`.

The `Calendar` class that you were trying to use was always poorly designed and is now long outdated. Instead I do as Amongalen suggested in a comment, I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Edit: For comparison `Calendar` has millisecond resolution, so would at best give you a substabtial loss of precision.

### Edit: More precise math

I couldn’t let the 85 nanoseconds be. Here’s a version that preserves precision as far as possible and gives the expected result:

```
    BigDecimal timeStamp = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger("C50204ECEC42EE92", 16));

    // To get the whole part and the fraction right, divide by 2^32
    BigDecimal bit32 = new BigDecimal(0x1_0000_0000L);
    BigDecimal secondsSince1900 = timeStamp.divide(bit32);

    // Convert seconds to nanos by multiplying by 1 000 000 000; round to long
    long nanosSince1900 = secondsSince1900.multiply(new BigDecimal(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1)))
            .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
            .longValueExact();

    Instant converted = epoch.plusNanos(nanosSince1900);
```

> 2004-09-27T03:18:04.922896300Z

1 nano too much? This is because I used half-up rounding in the call to `setScale`. If instead I truncate (using `RoundingMode.FLOOR`), I get the exact result from the explanation. So my version doesn’t lose more precision than theirs.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Thankyou, this works amazing! I agree the Calendar class is difficult to modify for higher accuracy. The "1096255084000" was just a test number I was using, its nothing to do with the code, I forgot to remove it in my question.

Comment: Excellent answer. I suggest adding an explicit caution of data loss, as the input resolves to hundreds of picoseconds which will be truncated to nanoseconds to fit *java.time*. And for completeness, perhaps add code showing how to go the other direction, to generate the text as seen in the example input. Lastly, I wonder if it might be more clear to use `Instant.ofEpochSecond` for first chunk of input, then add to that the fractional second represented in the second chunk of input.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes of course, my `ofEpochSecond` suggestion was dumb, given the different epoch reference. I’m taking more coffee now.